Can't get eslint working with Cypress in Visual Studio Code
I have installed eslint and eslint-plugin-cypress packages:
"eslint": "^9.4.0",
"eslint-plugin-cypress": "^3.3.0"

I have added eslint.config.js with the following code:
module.exports = [
    {
        "plugins": [
          "cypress"
        ]
      },
      {
        "rules": {
          "cypress/no-assigning-return-values": "error",
          "cypress/no-unnecessary-waiting": "error",
          "cypress/assertion-before-screenshot": "warn",
          "cypress/no-force": "warn",
          "cypress/no-async-tests": "error",
          "cypress/no-async-before": "error",
          "cypress/no-pause": "error"
        }
      },
      {
        "env": {
          "cypress/globals": true
        }
      }
];

However in my cy.js file I can quite happily add a pause:
describe('test', () => {
  it('test', () => {
    cy.pause();
});
})

And I don't see any message from eslint

Is there a reason you're trying to lint "through" cypress rather than just directly linting your code first? (Usually you first lint, because linting only matters for the source you work on, then you run your source code tests, then you run your build step, and then you run your integration tests against the build result (because testing against your source won't show you things that'll break for the user) so by the time you get to Cypress, everything should have already passed linting.

I had to install the ESLINT extension into Visual Studio Code before the packages would have any effect.
